# I have encounter TypeError: Must pass list-like as `names` error of pandas library while try to run osmnx.nearest_nodes function

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, geopandas, osmnx

I try to get nearest nodes to my origins for finding shortest routes. For this, I use osmnx.neraest_node function:
`orig_nodes = list(ox.nearest_nodes(G, brt_stops_reproj["x"],brt_stops_reproj["y"]))`

But I encounter  TypeError: Must pass list-like as `names`

`File ~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\osmnx\utils_graph.py:58, in graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes, edges, node_geometry, fill_edge_geometry)
55     else:
56         gdf_nodes = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, index=nodes)
**---> 58     gdf_nodes.index.rename("osmid", inplace=True)**
59     utils.log("Created nodes GeoDataFrame from graph")
61 if edges:

File ~\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:1791, in Index.set_names(self, names, level, inplace)
1788     raise TypeError("Names must be a string when a single level is provided.")
1790 if not is_list_like(names) and level is None and self.nlevels > 1:
**-> 1791     raise TypeError("Must pass list-like as `names`.")**
1793 if is_dict_like(names) and not isinstance(self, ABCMultiIndex):
1794     raise TypeError("Can only pass dict-like as `names` for MultiIndex.")

**TypeError: Must pass list-like as `names`.**
`

This error raised by  the neccesary for pandas dataframes that all columns' name  must be changed if you try to change a name of only one column. This problem originated in the script of  the function not originated in me. How can I solve this problem, Thanks for the answers

Comment: Please provide a complete standalone minimal reproducible code snippet.

Comment: And the version numbers of OSMnx and pandas

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem w/ OSMNX, but found a workaround using NetworkX:

```
import networkx as nx
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd

point_geom = brt_stops_reproj['geometry'].iloc[0]

distances={}
for node in G.nodes():
    node_geom = shapely.geometry.Point(node)
    distance = point_geom.distance(node_geom)
    distances[node]=distance
    
nearest_node = min(distances, key=distances.get)

print(nearest_node)
```

It should print a coordinate tuple.

I hope this helps. If anyone has a more elegant solution or knows it it's just a bug in OSMNX, I'd love to know.

Comment: You don't need to do a workaround with NetworkX, and it's not a bug in OSMnx. There still isn't a minimal reproducible code snippet in this question, so it's impossible to directly troubleshoot or answer. However, this question should be easy to answer if a reproducible code snippet is provided at some point.